# How to deal with inputs outside 0-1 range in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the example provided at http://www.tensorflow.org/get_started if I multiply the input by 2

```
x_data = np.float32(np.random.rand(2, 100))*2
```

I get non-sense output, while I expected to get the same solution.

```
0 [[ -67.06586456 -109.13352203]] [-7.67297792]
20 [[ nan  nan]] [ nan]
40 [[ nan  nan]] [ nan]
60 [[ nan  nan]] [ nan]
80 [[ nan  nan]] [ nan]
100 [[ nan  nan]] [ nan]
120 [[ nan  nan]] [ nan]
140 [[ nan  nan]] [ nan]
160 [[ nan  nan]] [ nan]
180 [[ nan  nan]] [ nan]
200 [[ nan  nan]] [ nan]
```

How does tensorflow handle inputs that are not in the 0-1 range?

*EDIT*: Using `AdagradOptimizer` works without an issue.

Comment: You probably diverged to infinity, and then you subtract infinity from infinity and get nan

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is that the example uses a very aggressive learning rate:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
```

This makes learning faster, but stops working if you change the problem a bit. A learning rate of `0.01` would be more typical:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
```

Now your modification works fine. :)